# Is there a cheap relay that can control voltage from stuff like bulb lights with a 5 V control output?

Tags: relay, mosfet, switch

I need to power a light bulb or something like 110 V or 220 V at normal amperage for TV or something at that range like a fan...

My micro-controller is an Arduino with 5 V out and 12 V max out trough transistor switch.

To my understanding a stepper motor drive could be a viable option to enable the relays... I can even control current, right?

[Up to 8 channels](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-1-2-4-6-8-Channel-Relay-Board-Module-Optocoupler-LED-for-Arduino-PiC-ARM-AVR-/371642356980?var=&hash=item56879c54f4:m:mgnWPfoXCbjWi3z8ochdzrw)

[Could this work better?](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5V-8-Channel-Low-Level-Trigger-Arduino-Solid-State-Relay-Module-with-Fuse-250V2A-/191963613200?hash=item2cb1ec4810:g:fc8AAOSwwPhWlcTF)

Comment: Just remember SSRs are not good with fluorescent light bulbs as there is  a small current through the relay in closed state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Which to use where**

Ok, so I've narrow the 2 main choices that you have : either a MOSFET or a RELAY. For higher voltages, it is much safer to go with a relay but for higher current, you might as well use a power MOSFET.

**Option 1 - Relays**

They are mainly used to control already made stuff like a bulb using main's voltage. They are also used to control stuff like a fan (pre built), lamp, and many more. Relays are also simple to wire and don't quire much electronics skills. The main disadvantage of a relay is that they are not as good as MOSFETs when it comes to current handling.

***Advantages: Light bulb, stuff bought from the sotre (TVs, fans, small heater), house automation, laundry, house heater, fridge***

**Opition 2 - MOSFETs**

**IMPORTANT NOTICE : YOU CANNOT USE A MOSFET WITH MAIN'S VOLTAGE**

MOSFETs are great when it comes to kick some voltage in to your devices. I remember as a kid, I use to stock these in NERF guns. Motors will instantly start with MOSFETS!. For even higher current control. Try power mosfets, they are designed for high current. Also know that mosfets are bad in the way that they tend to warm up a lot (if the current is high).

***Advantages: Neon light, motors, things that need to be responsive (drone motors), things that need to be precise (PWM)***

In conclusion, relays master the world of high voltages and MOSFETs the world of high current!

Comment: MOSFETs have an intrinsic body diode between source and drain. You want this diode to be reverse-biased when the MOSFET is off. Hence MOSFETs are not good for switching AC, and mains is AC.

Comment: Well thats why I said that Relays are better for mains voltage. Shoud I modify anything?

Comment: Yes, make it crystal clear that a MOSFET is unsuitable for switching mains. It is absolutely not obvious from your answer as it stands now.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, I included the notice, aything else

Comment: It think it is clear enough.

Comment: More understandable but if you could give an example on AC relay handling and if an arduino is able to handle it without external modules I could accept this answer! Thanks

Comment: I know solid state relays are better but they are not cheap! I want to know if I can wire an 8 channel relay module to control 110v to 220v devices!! Like the one in the link provided

Comment: Quick link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLFQ8sBWc80. He uses a cheap 2-channel but a 8-channel should work. See how he does it and follow CAREFULLY. I can't insist on safety with relays!

Comment: So, yes you can use the one from the link that you provided.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [5V Solid-State Relay module](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VRUAHLE) to control light bulbs. They cost $4-6 from US-based suppliers and $1-3 from a Chinese supplier. Just hook up the supply to the center pin and the load to either the NO or NC pin. Supply 5V to the module and wire a digital pin to the module to control it.

Comment: Nice one and thanks but could you confirm if any of the ones I found on ebay works as well?? Check my edit

Comment: @DarkXDroid The seller did not include part numbers or manufacturer names so I couldn't lookup any datasheets. A relay with a max 250VAC and max 10A rating will be able to handle any standard light bulb. The main concern is how much current is required to trigger the relay. Arduino I/O pins can only supply (or source) ~20mA so if the relay draws more than that it will damage the board. The relays in the link might work but you can't know for sure without the datasheet. I know that Sainsmart relay modules are safe to use with Arduino digital pins.

Comment: I got ´´Omron 5V solid state relay 240V 2A, output with resistive fuse 240V 2A?´´

I think itś not enough so I´ll search for 250vac with an 10A, right?

Comment: Better Solution?

http://www.ebay.com/itm/ESP8266-2-Kanal-Channel-Relais-Modul-5V-10A-250VAC-10A-30VDC-Optokoppler-Arduino-/282185010711?hash=item41b3898e17:g:k~gAAOSw6n5Xuwl4

Comment: Another one? http://www.ebay.com/itm/8-channel-relay-module-optocoupler-isolated-relay-5V10A-opto-relay-board-SN513-2-/291140196745?hash=item43c94ed989:g:lTMAAMXQNo5TZwnw

Comment: Is there a way to use transistors as switches? Or are there any other better solution without frying pins or ic?

Comment: @DarkXDroid I was about to say transistors or better: mosfets. A mosfet is a good way to switch with Arduino because mosfets require voltage and not current to switch. Many mosfets are designed to trigger between 1~3 volts. You can then supply 5V from the Arduino 5V pin (which can give up to 1A current) and use that to switch the relay.

Comment: @Len I saw about mosfets but could understand if they were better options!! Thanks! Could you recommend me one of the option in my comments? I like to make sure If one of them is better than the other based on your exp

Comment: @Len This mosfet is a good option http://www.ebay.com/itm/Four-Channel-4-Route-MOSFET-Button-IRF540-V2-0-MOSFET-Switch-Module-Arduino-/200959373944?hash=item2eca1cb278:g:B1oAAOSwwo1Xdeup

Comment: You don't need a shield or something. Just get the single mosfet, make sure gate is pulled down and you're basically good to go.

Comment: Something like a IRF640 with TO-220 package should be good. Continuous drain can be as high as 18A, so no worries there. Just put 5V on the Gate and it turns on, if you don't put 5V on it, the pulldown resistor will ground Gate and that turns off the mosfet.

Comment: @Len can I simplify it by using a motor drive? Cos I have 2 in hands ... Check my edit... But I can change current on at least 4 pins per drive with the module I have without worry on frying the micro

Comment: @DarkXDroid I don't know about that. Never used a motor driver like that. I'd stick to mosfets.

Answer (score 1):

The first one you have seems fine (in my opinion). Note though that relays are something not to be cheap with. They can cause dangerous accidents if you buy them from a cheap supplier (chinese). I'll always go for a local supplier (don't know where you live so I can't tell). Make sure to check Radioshack and stores like that.

Also make sure that you find one with a datasheet. No datasheet = no specs. No specs = you don't know the max of your relay which is BAD. The max of a relay should be known and respected or something bad can happen.

Comment: First or second option? I understand that low grade equip can cause a disaster but I already have a solution... besides this is prototyping and I want to understand the technology and limits. That why I put a range devices that I could control. But you got a valid point with security and end capacity

Comment: first option is the one that i prefer

Comment: I´m grateful for everything .... I´go with that at first

Comment: In my experience, the relays purchased from a local or US supplier are all made in China anyway.

Comment: My exp tells me the same lol the thing is that I should pay more to stay on the safe side

Comment: @ThatAintWorking, if you buy it from a US supplier and it fails, you can sue them for $ (only if the product is defective). Buy it from Chine, suffer the consequences...